# Why bot don't send photo?

Tags: python, bots, telegram, chatbot, aiogram

my problem is that bot don't send photo, which it got from user(admin).Bot have to send photo all users in database.

```
@dp.message_handler(state='send_photo')
async def send(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    photo = message.photo
    users = data.get_user()
    for el in users:
        try:
            await bot_name.send_photo(el[0],photo)
            if int(el[1]) != 1:
                data.set_active(el[0], 1)
        except:
            data.set_active(el[0], 0)
    await bot_name.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'The command was executed successfully!')
    await state.finish()
```

I tried to edit something with different ways and more times, but it was unsuccessful.

Comment: WShat does it do instead ? Any error log ? Are you sure the users list is not empty ?

Comment: @Itération122442, Instead, nothing happens and the error log is also empty, the list of users is full

Answer (score 1):

When you get the image through **message_handler**, it comes to you in the [message](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#message) as an [array](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#message:%7E:text=about%20the%20file-,photo,-Array%20of%20PhotoSize) as shown below.

```json
"photo": [
   {
    "file_id": "AgACAgIAAxkBAAEVtjtknKX0aBCod2........",
    "file_unique_id": "AQADEsw....",
    "file_size": 1199,
    "width": 90,
    "height": 70
   },
   {
    "file_id": "AgACAgIAAxkBAAEVtAAwIAA20AAy8E...........",
    "file_unique_id": "AQADEsw.......",
    "file_size": 10989,
    "width": 320,
    "height": 250
   },
   {
    "file_id": "AgACAgIAAxkBAAEVtjtknKX0aBCod22XuJ.......",
    "file_unique_id": "AQADEsw....",
    "file_size": 39728,
    "width": 800,
    "height": 624
   },
   {
    "file_id": "AgACAgIAAxkBAAEVtjtknKX0a.........",
    "file_unique_id": "AQADEswx......",
    "file_size": 52533,
    "width": 1000,
    "height": 780
   }
  ]
```

where `image[0]` is the lowest quality image and `photo[-1]` is the highest quality image.

You should rewrite the method as follows.

```py
await bot_name.send_photo(el[0],photo[-1].file_id)
```

you can read more here

[sendPhoto](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendphoto)

[file_id](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendphoto:%7E:text=Photo%20to%20send.%20Pass%20a-,file_id,-as%20String%20to%20send%20a)